causal effect and exogeneity in small samples vs in large samples
Under this title two questions are included.
In regression of Y on X and controls Z with random error e,

In small sample if strictly exogeneity, i.e. E(e|X,Z)=0, is satisfied, does it means the coefficient of X has the meaning of causality?
In large sample, can the condition of strictly exogeneity be relaxed to uncorrelated, that is Cov(e,X)=0 and Cov(e,Z)=0, to describe causality? If the answer is yes,please derive the reason with formula.

I've found lots of books and papers (for example on IV)  discuss correlation instead of exogeneity. I've checked some textbooks where they only explain the properties changed from unbiased in small samples to consistent in large samples which is irrelevant with causality.

Strict exogeneity, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon\mid X,Z]=0$, is a population-level condition, so whether it holds or not has to be analyzed with infinite samples.
Strict exogeneity implies $\operatorname{cov}(\epsilon,X\mid Z)=0$ but, in general, the latter does not imply a causal interpretation. For instance, consider the true causal model to be:
$$
Y_i = \alpha + \beta X_i + \gamma Z_i + \underbrace{\delta C_i + \eta_i}_{\epsilon_i},
$$
where $\delta\neq 0$ and $C_i$ is an unobserved confounder, leading to $\epsilon_i\not\perp X_i\mid Z_i$ and $\eta_i\perp X_i\mid Z_i,C_i$. Then:
$$
\operatorname{cov}(\epsilon_i,X_i\mid Z)= \operatorname{cov}(\delta C_i + \eta_i,X_i\mid Z_i) = \delta\operatorname{cov}(C_i, X_i\mid Z_i)+0
$$
Zero correlation does not imply independence. Thus, it might be the case that $\operatorname{cov}(C_i, X_i\mid Z_i)=0$, so  $\operatorname{cov}(\epsilon,X\mid Z)=0$ holds, but $\beta$ does not have a causal interpretation due to the omitted latent confounder $C_i$.
Yet, $\beta$ could have a causal interpretation but under the conditions that: i) no latent confounder $C_i$ exists, and ii) the true causal model is instead:
$$
Y_i = \alpha + \beta X_i + \gamma Z_i + \epsilon_i,
$$
with $\epsilon_i\perp X_i\mid Z_i$.

In your case constructed, I feel the variable Z can be omitted which would not damage the  $beta$ as the level of causal effect. Which quantity should be used to evaluate the causal effect? I think it is the partial effect of X to the conditional expectation of Y, which is unchanged.

Besides, if  \epsilon is uncorrelated with X under Z,  strictly exogeneity doesn't hold. Therefore, your counterexample is not correct.

The variable $Z$ can only be omitted if it is not essential for identification. If $Z$ is a confounder, it cannot be excluded from a model with coefficients to be estimated from data. The meaning and value of the coefficient $\beta$ depend on the variables included in the model (whether $Z$ and/or $C$ are present). I have edited the second part to clarify statements concerning zero correlation.

There is some case that Cov(\epsilon, X|Z)=0 but  \epsilon and X is independent conditional on Z, which is the key point I've got in your counterexample.    However, in my question, strictly exogeneity is more strict than correlation. Your example has weaken my description.   Although there is some case that strictly exogenous but conditional dependent, to quantify the causal effect could be enough.

The counterexample is actually the other way around: There is some case that $\operatorname{cov}(\epsilon,X\mid Z)=0$ but $\epsilon$ and $X$ are NOT independent conditional on $Z$. This example is to show that the answer for your question #2 (about weakening assumptions towards correlations) is "no, in general, without further assumptions". That's true for any causal interpretation based on correlations.

That makes sense. Thanks a lot.  Therefore, we should only discuss some statistical properties on estimates in large sample which is not too much about causality. After all, confounders will affact identification of causality no matter in small or large samples.  I'm curious people often analyse uncorrelation instead of conditional independent or strictly exogenous. After all, in large  sample, $cov(\epsilon,X|Z)=0$ has a weaker name "weak exogeneity" or just "exogeneity". To identify causality, the name is ambiguous.   @Johan de Aguas
